# How to assign a matrix from a text file to a variable in C?

Tags: c, file, matrix

I'm using the scanf() function to assign the matrix to the variable, but I want to call the matrix from a text file.

Here is my code:

```
  int rows;
  int columns;
  float weight;
  float step;

  printf("Enter the number of rows and columns of the matrix.\n");
  scanf("%d%d", &rows,&columns);

  printf("Enter step for the weight.\n");
  scanf("%f", &step);

  int a[rows][columns], b[rows][columns],i,j;
  float c[rows][columns];

  printf("Enter the First matrix->");
  for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
      for(j=0;j<columns;j++)
           scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
  printf("\nEnter the Second matrix->");
  for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
      for(j=0;j<columns;j++)
           scanf("%d",&b[i][j]);
```

Comment: Can you provide example input and explain how your program's behavior is different from what you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2 possibles solutions:

1) You can keep your code without modifications. And then you have to call your binary program in this way:

```
$ myprogram < myfile.txt
```

in this solution the stdin stream will be replaced by the `myfile.txt` file stream.

2) use `fscanf()` to read from file instead of using `scanf()` which read from stdin

Comment: Thanks. I used your 2nd solution and it worked. I just started learning C recently and didn't know about fscanf().